# Spinor representation of $SO(d+1,1)$

Tags: quantum-spin, group-representations, spinors

I have been looking over the internet for a resource that tells me the number of dimensions of a spin $s-1$ spinor representation of $SO(d+1,1)$, but unfortunately have yet to be able to find it. In some sense, this dimension also tells us the dimension of a rank $s-1$ Killing spinor of $SO(d+1,1)$.

Comment: You can find this kind of information in textbooks on supergravity, for instance the one by Daniel Z. Freedman and Antoine Van Proeyen, chapter 3.

Comment: Do you happen to have the exact pages? It seems that whichever Freedman and Proeyen had concerned up to spin-3/2 tensors.